# Cannot ssh from host to guest os in Virtual Box

Tags: ssh, firewall, switch, traceroute

I have a windows machine with virtual box installed. I have ubuntu VM within the virtual box. If I setup my vm's network to use NAT, and setup port forwarding to forward from my localhost to the 10.x.x.x IP of the VM, i can ssh into the vm from my windows.

```
ssh uname@localhost
```

If I setup the VM's network to use Bridged Adapter(i.e. the VM is seen as another computer within the existing network), I cannot ssh into it from windows. However, if  I create another linux vm using Bridged adapter, can ssh between vms using IP address from the bridged adapter.

my question is, why can't i ssh into any of my VM using Bridged adapter?

Is the traffic blocked at switch level? But I can't really confirm this. I have tried the following with no luck

- adding ip from the vm and port to proxy exception in Internet explorer(i'm behind proxy)
- telneting to VM_IP
- Running tracert. ICMP is blocked on the network. won't work
- all the tcp ping or tcp traceroute tools i have required elevated installation, which I don't have access
- no outgoing firewall restriction is enabled.

Comment: Another possibility is network MTU; see [the "VPN MTU limit breaks ssh connection" thread](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2013-November/031775.html).

Comment: Usually it's a missing or misconfigured route. Can you add interface config and routing table of both hosts?